# Multiple class for input element

Tags: html, css, input

I have one style (box shadow on Focus) for all input fields in my site, but for the search input field I need a different style (no box shadow). How do I go about doing this with HTML and CSS. Below is my current CSS and HTML code snippet for your perusal.

HTML:

```
<div class="top-search">
<table width="190" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="175" height="22" align="left" valign="middle">
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
<input class="top-search-field noshadow" type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input class="top-search-field noshadow" type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
<?php } ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div><!-- top-search ends -->
```

CSS:

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password'], textarea {
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #0066CC;
/*padding: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;*/
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFFFFF;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
}

input[type='text']:focus, input[type='password']:focus, textarea:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}

input.noshadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`box-shadow: none` doesn't cancel out the box shadow property.

`box-shadow: 0 0` does the trick (with `outline: none`, to remove Chromes default focus outline blur)

Then you need to target the `:focus` as well:

```
input.noshadow, input.noshadow:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

**Please Note** - to overwrite the properties given by `input[type=text]` you need to use `input.noshadow`. Simply using `.noshadow` will not work. It's a little bit complicated, but it could be good to have a [read about CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/).

Demo

```css
input[type='text'], input[type='password'], textarea {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
}

input[type='text']:focus, input[type='password']:focus, textarea:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
}

input.noshadow, input.noshadow:focus {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 ;
outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="I have a shadow :D" />
<input type="text" class="noshadow" value="I am shadowless :O" />
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the reply misterManSam. I am going to try this out... but I have one more question in this regard...

Can I apply more than one class to your 2nd input in addition to noshadow, like:
<input type="text" class="noshadow top-search-field" value="I am shadowless :O" />

Will this work?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple classes. Just make sure that the exception class (in this case `.noshadow`) is ***underneath*** the rest of the input CSS so that it will overwrite the shadow.

Comment: **Also note** - to overwrite the property given by `input[type=text]` you need to use `input.shadow` to overwrite. Simply using `.shadow` will not overwrite it. It's a little bit complicated, but it could be good to have a [read about CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/).

Comment: Thank you so very much... I greatly appreciate you taking the time and effort. I have also removed the border along with the shadow and applied both the classes successfully. Thank you once again. Sorry I cannot vote as I do not have enough reputation.